# php - class property issues

Tags: php, class

I am trying to get the class's property in PHP

```
class Test(){
    public function import($data) {
        $im = new import($this, $data);
        $im->getInfo();

        $this->fileInfo = $im->getRecord();
        new ImportData($this, $this->fileInfo);
        return true;
    }

    public function getFilePath(){
        return $this->fileInfo;
    }
}
```

In my other file.

```
$import = new Test();

$filePath = $import ->getFilePath();

//$filePath returns nothing becasue $this->fileInfo is not init yet.  


//my other codes here.
//my other codes here.

//call import method here.
$import ->import($data);
```

I need to call `getFilePath` before `import` method but I can only get the `$this->fileInfo` in `import` method. 
Are there anyways around this? Thanks so much!

Comment: `class test(){...}` is not right. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php

Comment: Sorry it's just a quick typo. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Yeah, your code doesn't make much sense.  Like, when you create and populate a new ImportData object (`new ImportData($this, $this->fileInfo)`), but don't assign it to anything, resulting in an object without a way to actually refer to it.

Comment: You need A before B but A only works after B. No, time traval is sadly not yet a PHP feature. If you could elaborate _why_ you think A needs the be before B we can perhaps suggest alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

one of many examples... use your construct method inside your class to initialize variables and methods you will need class wide.

```
class TestClass
{
   private $variable // should initialized in construct to be available via $this->variable class wide
   public function __construct($data)
    {
       // initialize methods and code here so they will be available throughout the calss
       $this->variable = $this->getinfo($data); // this will be initialized when you instantiate your class object.
    }

   //etc methods
}
```

Comment: `class Test(){...` is invalid syntax :)

Comment: updated as per your comment above